# How to search document with consecutive words with wildcard in Elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

How to find all documents with wildcard where words go one after another. For example, I have two documents:

```
{"text": "people in Ukraine elected a new president"}
{"text": "Ukrainians chose a new president"}
```

I try search use wildcard and quote with slop distances, used query_string:

```
{
    "_source": ["_id", "text"],
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": '"ukrain* president*"~3',
            "analyze_wildcard": True
           }
    }
}
```

But elastic return empty hits.

I use `standard` analyzer with removing stop words, without stemmer because I also want search by exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here is with the Analyzer. You are using the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

So this analyzer will split your string `people in Ukraine elected a new president` into 7 different words i.e. `people`, `in`, `Ukraine` and so on.
Now when to try to search a wildcard `ukrain* president*` this doesn't match to any of the analyzed words that are stored as inverted indexes in Elasticsearch.

Also, I see you are using the `query_string` to search regex which is the incorrect way of doing this. For this Elasticsearch has [`wildcard` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).